# Swing - Changing the content of a panel using UpdateUI

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe, actionlistener

I am going through a legacy application which is using Swing and i am struggling to figure out how the screens are changing when a user clicks a button. One of the reasons i cant figure this out is because this is the first time i am using Swing.  I have read a book and got the basics but still struggling.

Basically, the screen i am looking at has a JSplitPane which has a number of shortcut buttons on the left and an empty pane on the right. When i click on the button, the right side pane is populated with a different screen depending on the button pressed.

Going through the code, i was expecting somewhere that there will be something that calls a setVisible() method depending on which button is pressed.

The actionPerformed method for each of the shortcut buttons looks something like this:

```
void shortCutBtn_actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
   propertyChangeListeners.firePropertyChange("selectedShortCut", previousShortCutSel, currentShortCutSel);
   mainPanel.updateUI();
  }
```

I have gone through most of the code and came to a conclusion that the above code is what is causing the frame switching but i dont understand how that is happening.

Each screen is identified by a numeric constant. In the above code example, previousShortCutSel and previousShortCutSel refer to a numeric value that represents individual screens screen.

I have tried to look for documentation of how updateUI() works but i am lost. How does the above cause the content of the right panel of the JSplitPanel to be updated with a new screen?

Comment: Have you had a look at the propertychange listeners that seem to be present

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Thanks @DavidKroukamp - I didn't understand how the PropertyChangeListener worked but just looked it up and it led me to a different class that makes more sense. There is a propertyChange() method in that class that has everything else i was looking for. If you reply as an answer i will accept - Thanks

Comment: @AndrewThompson i was only interested in those two lines of code i posted as they are the lines i was struggling with. - Thanks

Comment: *"i was only interested in those two lines of code"*  My bad, I thought you were interested in an answer.

Comment: @DavidKroukamp: I concur with ziggy.

Comment: @AndrewThompson arguably, those two lines are enough to find the at least one problem in the code :-) And they seem to indicate that the previous coder left a terrible mess behind ... good luck needed to clean that up!

Comment: @kleopatra  *"arguably, those two lines are enough to find .. at least one problem in the code :-)"*  If I read code snippets, we might not need to argue..  ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per comments by ziggy (glad it helped)

Have a look at the `PropertyChangeListener`s that appear to be added in the code. In particular the `propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent e)` method is where the code which changes the content will be present.

+1 to trashgod nice example/advice as always

Comment: I suspect that `mainPanel` should register as a `PropertyChangeListener` and invoke `repaint()` in response.

Answer (score 9):

This is not an appropriate use of `updateUI()`, which "Resets the UI property to a value from the current look and feel."  As the example itself may be unreliable, consider studying another. [`GoogleOlympiad`](https://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/googleolympiad), for example, sets a label's icon using a (cached) image.

```
ImageIcon image = getImage(index);
imageLabel.setIcon(image);
```

[image]
<sub>(source: [drjohnbmatthews at sites.google.com](https://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/_/rsrc/1219654665541/googleolympiad/go1.png))</sub>