# How update an ImageIcon from JButton/JLabel

Tags: java, image, swing, jlabel, imageicon

I'm  having problems updating ( or refreshing) an Icon from button after closing a modal dialog. The image is basically overwritten by some actions of `JDialog`.

This is my code:

```
conf = new Configurar(this, true,control);           
conf.setVisible(true); // Open dialog
System.out.println("Cerrado"); // Check if is closed (debug)
String logo =(String)config.get("logo"); // get path from image
File newIcon =new File(logo); // Desesperate try
ImageIcon img = new ImageIcon(newIcon.getAbsolutePath()); 
btn_main_image.setIcon(img);
this.update(btn_main_image.getGraphics());
btn_main_image.updateUI(); // First Try
this.repaint(); // Second Try
```

The first time it works fine, but when I open the dialog and change the image remains the same.

Comment: It will be likely that at time of deployment, the `logo` image is not a `File` on the file system, but a resource inside a Jar.  If that is so, it must be accessed by `URL`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
conf = new Configurar(this, true,control);           
conf.setVisible(true); // Some kind of file chooser ??
File newIcon =new File(logo);
if (newIcon.exists()) {
   ImageIcon img = new ImageIcon(newIcon.getAbsolutePath()); 
   btn_main_image.setIcon(img);
   //this.update(btn_main_image.getGraphics()); // WHAT IS THIS?!?!?!
   //btn_main_image.updateUI(); // NO NO NO, this has nothing to do with refreshing the graphics, it's L&F stuff
   btn_main_image.invalidate();
   // Use this ONLY if invalidate doesn't work...
   btn_main_image.revalidate();
   btn_main_image.repaint();
}
```

Comment: Thanks !! ... but didn't work :c the button have the same image after "setIcon".

Comment: please to remove `btn_main_image.invalidate();` required for `OverlayLayout`, use `flush()` for `ImageIcon` instead of `invalidate();`

Comment: `ImageIcon` doesn't have a `flush` or `invalidate` method??  `invalidate` may be better called on the parent, but it's only going to cause the layout manager to be marked as invalid.  `validate` may be a better choice

Comment: @rafuru can you verify that the code entered the `if(newIcon.exists())` branch. If not, then there's part of your problem...

Comment: +1 Because it's a bound property, `setIcon()` alone should be sufficient, as suggested [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12885346/230513). Sounds like a problem elsewhere in the code.