# JButton needs to display array of images

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, jbutton

I have a set of images stored in an array and I need to display them like a slide show. There are two JButtons next and previous that allow the user to see the images. However I can't get the buttons to work. Any suggestion?

Thanks

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class slides extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

    // Data Field
    private final ImageIcon imageArray[];
    private ImageIcon image;

    JButton nextButton;
    JButton prevButton;

    int page = 0;
    int nextPage = page + 1;
    int prevPage = page - 1;
    int numOfSlides = 28;


    // Obtains and stores slides in imageArray
    public slides() {
        imageArray = new ImageIcon[numOfSlides];
        for (int i = 0; i < imageArray.length; i++) {
            imageArray[i] = new ImageIcon("Slide " + (i + 1) + ".png");
        }
    }

    // Displays slides
    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        boolean began = true;

        // creates next button
        nextButton = new JButton("next");
        nextButton.setBounds(400, 574, 70, 30);
        nextButton.addActionListener(this);
        add(nextButton);

        // creates previous button
        prevButton = new JButton("previous");
        prevButton.setBounds(0, 574, 85, 30);
        prevButton.addActionListener(this);
        add(prevButton);

        // displays slide 1
        if (began == true) {
            image = imageArray[page];
            image.paintIcon(this, g, 0, 0);
            began = false;
        }

        // displays other slides based on preference
        if (page == nextPage) {
            image = imageArray[page + 1];
            image.paintIcon(this, g, 0, 0);
            nextPage = page + 1;
            prevPage = page - 1;
        }
        if (page == prevPage) {
            nextPage = page + 1;
            prevPage = page - 1;
            image = imageArray[page - 1];
            image.paintIcon(this, g, 0, 0);
        }

        // Removes buttons accordingly
        if(page == imageArray.length - 1) {
            remove(nextButton);
        }
        if(page == 0){
            remove(prevButton);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        if (event.getSource() == nextButton) {
            page++;
            image = imageArray[page];
        }
        if (event.getSource() == prevButton) {
            page--;
            image = imageArray[page];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What's exactly the problem, i.e. what do you mean by "can't get the buttons to work"? Can you show us a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: paintIcon meaning that you have to override paintIcon, then  paintComponent is useless

Comment: remove everything from code inside paintComponent (can be executed a few times per one second) rest is in Oracle tutorial

Comment: I'm sorry mKorbel. Could you help me understand what you said please? Am I to write a new method paintIcon and then move all the code from paintComponent into paintIcon?

Comment: not 1. remove all code lines after boolean began = true; :-) theoretically you added 40-120 JButtons to JPanel per one second (revalidate a repaint can show that), from Key and Mouse Events (firing a new event paintComponent) 2. code inside actionlistener missing code line repaint(firing a new event to paintComponent programatically)

Comment: again everything about is in Oracle tutorial - Graphics2D

Comment: I think you may have saved the day! Thank you very much mKorbel.

Answer (score 4):

> Any suggestion?

- There's no need to override `paintComponent()`; instead, use `setIcon()` on an existing `JLabel`. A complete example is cited [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12884972/swing-changing-the-content-of-a-panel-using-updateui/12885346#12885346).
- Don't use `setBounds()`; instead, `pack()` the enclosing `Window` to let the components adopt their preferred sizes.

[image]
<sub>(source: [drjohnbmatthews at sites.google.com](https://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/_/rsrc/1219654665541/googleolympiad/go1.png))</sub>