# Is it possible to specify the path of a chosen image with a variable?

Tags: java, image, swing, path, label

Is it possible to determine the path of a chosen image with a variable? like this:

```
private JLabel label = new JLabel();
int number = 1;
label.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/image" + number + ".png")));
```

In this case it does not work, but my idea might be clear. In this case I could just simply change the variable name in order to change the path of my image. Does anybody know how to do so?

Comment: *"In this case it does not work"*  In that case, the path is wrong.  Confirm it to yourself using the hard coded string of `"/image1.png"`..

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Closed...

Comment: A complete example is cited [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12885346/230513).